# Facing warning message while import the service or child component in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, import, dynamic-import

Am facing some warning messages like this

> [ng] Warning:
> ./src/pages/employee_listpage/employee_listpage.html
> 1:0 [ng] Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0) [ng] You may need
> an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders
> are configured to process this file. See
> https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Function calling from pages for dynamic import the page (employee_listpage)

```
const classInstance = await this.serviceFile.dynamicImport('employee_listpage');
console.log('classInstance:: ', classInstance);
```

dynamicImport function definition in service file

```
 async dynamicImport(className) {
        const viewRef = {
            loadChildren: () => import(`../../pages/${className}/${className}`).then(m => m[className])
        }
        return viewRef.loadChildren();
    }
```

Comment: You need the file extension as well. employee_listpage.ts

Comment: Yeah it's working. But I have one more doubt.. how do I import .enum files and .type files 

sample code for .enum.ts 
`import viewRef = await import(src/core/models/`${className}`.enum.ts);` 

for .type.ts 
`import viewRef = await import(src/core/models/`${className}`.type.ts);`

@Bertramp Is it correct ?